# MySql Insert not successful with successful connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a simple sql into my MySql DB using a Compute Engine VM server. Here is my php code

```
$host = "173.194.248.20"; //server
$db = "Test"; //database name
$user = "root"; //dabases user name
$pwd = "password"; //password`

$title = "title";




//connecting to server and creating link to database
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

if($link)
{
    echo("Connected. ");
}
else
{
    echo("Not connected.");
}


//perform the insert using mysqli
$result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO BOOK(Content) VALUES('$title')");


if($result)
{
    echo("Insert Completed.");
}
else
{
    echo("Did not complete insert.");
}
```

When I run this code I get "Connected. Did not complete insert." I am not sure why it cant insert. If I am correct, if it connects and all the values add up, then the insert is supposed to be successful. I have added an image of my DB structure. I am unsure if I just cannot see the error or if the problem exists else where. Also, is there a way to print out the reason why a sql was not successful? [image]

Comment: Try echoing `mysqli_error($link)` to get the reason for the error.

Comment: @EdGibbs This is what it tells me even though the image above says otherwise "Table 'Test.BOOK' doesn't exist"

Comment: @EdGibbs apparently it needed to be case sensitive. When I changed the query to "INSERT INTO Book(...)" The query was successful. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent - glad you got it figured out!